# Is it possible to set auto-completion for 2 languages in Notepad++?

Tags: html, css, autocomplete, notepad++

Is there a way to make the autocomplete for both HTML & CSS in notepad++? 
my autocomplete is currently set only on the HTML, so my problem is that when I type color: it doesn't suggest to me the range of colors like I saw in some video it can do.

Or, when I type font-family: it doesn't suggest all the font families to me.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Maybe it's a good idea to have your CSS separate from your HTML in different files :)

Comment: The whole idea, in this case, is to be able to edit the code in the same file. I add the css in the head & the html in the body. this is what I learned so far. I'm new at this (but you probably guessed that already:)  )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question is that it can't be done with notepad++. the video in which I saw it done was made with [Brackets](http://brackets.io). so this action can be done with this tool.

Answer (score 0):

On Notepad++ I think you have to go to:

**Settings > Preference > Auto-Completion**, there you should be able to enable the auto-completetion.

It should look something like this.

[image]

However, if your CSS & HTML are on the same file using `script` tags, you may confuse the editor, which is why is may not be working.. Let me know if that is the case.

Comment: Yes, it was like that when I asked that and yes I'm writing it in the same file. I know there's a way to fix this because in the video of my instructor I see him typing that (also in the same file) & it suggests to him the correct autocompletion.

Comment: Have you got function completion selected ? If not try that.

Comment: Yes, this option was already enabled when I asked my question.